# how to grep .txt .tar.gz .py file once

Tags: shell, grep

i can use

```
ls|grep \.py$
```

to list all ends with .py file,but it's seems hard for me to grep all .py & .txt & .tar.gz file once

any one could give me a hand

Comment: respectively `ls -d *.py *.txt *.tar.gz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls | grep -E '\.(py|txt|tar\.gz)$'
```

Answer (score 1):

No need external commands. Use the shell(bash/ksh)

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.{txt,tar,gz,py}
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: or even just: `ls *.{txt,tar,gz,py}`

Comment: only when his purpose is just that, listing only.